# Как настраивать рандом?

Tags: случайные-числа, python-3.6

Программирую на python мне стало интересно как в играх наслаивают шанс выпадения предмето.

Comment: Как формулу напишут, так и наслоится. Обычно просто умножением - `x = base * (1 + chance1) * (1 + chance2)`

Comment: уточните вопрос. В зависимости от алгоритма может вообще никаких настроек не быть, для некоторых алгоритмов иногда seed полезно явно задать, иногда сам алгоритм выбрать (скорость, стат.свойства, предсказуемость)

Comment: Ну допустим если я не очень опытный программист и мне нужно написать текстовую RPG и там нужна такая формула (желательно самая простая)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Блин пока ждал ответа чуть не помер и до пёр уж сам до кого-то решения проблемы

```
def zon_itm(self):
    #определяет тип
    a=random.randrange(1,1000)
    if a <= 1000 and a >= 250:
        return ('обычный')
    elif a < 250 and a >= 100:
        return ('редкий')
    elif a < 100 and a >= 10:
        return ('эпический')
    elif a < 10 and a >= 1:
        return ('легендарный')
```

Comment: Сравнения ``a <= 1000`` и  ``a >= 1`` можно убрать, от них нет никакой пользы. Также  можно убрать первое сравнение в каждом ``elif``, они тоже не приносят ничего нового, а только усложняют чтение кода.

Comment: self в `def zon_itm(self):` тоже не нужен (self не используется) -- этот метод можно сделать функцией, либо статичным методом класса. Скобки в return тоже не нужны. Проверки диапазона усложнены -- достаточно понатыкать что `a  <= значение` чтобы определить ценность

Comment: Вот, посмотрите: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/3f6237865d421885db1eef9d6986b03a73269d32/game__get_random_rarity_item.py

Comment: @gil9red    а что делает  __author__ = 'ipetrash'  эта строчка

Comment: @gil9red ??????

Comment: @gil9red и нет self в моём случае обязателен ведь это часть class

Comment: `__author__` специальная переменная. self не является обязательным и я выше уже объяснил почему

Comment: Но без self не работает @gil9red хе

Comment: У вас не работает, а у меня заработает, хе :) Тот метод можно сделать статичным методом класса, тогда нужно будет убрать self из аргументов метода и на строку выше метода добавить `@staticmethod`

Comment: Кто знает я лишь делаю как могу да если знали раньше чего же молчали